# Setting default values according to user input Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an app which has a bonus system for users. According to certain transactions, they receive a bonus which is staggered according to value of the transaction.

Now there are default percentages for each bonus level. But I was wondering how to dynamically set those default values. The admin of the app should be able to change them.
For now I created a dummy record that holds those default values. If the admin decides to change the levels, this record gets updated.

But is the a more elegant solution to change default values for a model?

Comment: Would default values in html input tags work for you?

Comment: No, because I calculate the bonus without going via a bonus form, it shouldjust get generated when a transacition is made

Comment: I would do it with a new model for the bonus levels. The admin will be able to manage this percentages and levels. For example, the new model would be have two columns: percentage and threshold. If the transaction amount is higher than the threshold, then you will applicate the percentage of the bonus level. The admin will be able to add or update the bonus levels without having any impact on existing transactions

Comment: @excanxr So that would mean there is one record, which holds the default values. That was my idea too, but I don't find it very elegant, because this record will float around with only the purpose of holding the default values

Comment: I think that was a convenient way for this scenario. Since the value needs to be changed dynamically by an actor that is not the system itself(admin). It makes sense to have this record that is going to be updated. I don't know why you want to do it differently?

Comment: @Clara Not only one record, as much as you want for each threshold. :) I'm using something like this for the service fees on one of my app and it's the easier way to do it I think. It doesn't require any maintenance when it's launched, the admin has just to adjust the values

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. So I guess there is no magical way of setting default values as a callback on the model and then change those somehow?!

Comment: @Clara Well, if you want a default value, on the model who has a transaction, you just need a `before_create` callback where you put the default value of your choice, then update this value when you'll know the transaction amount to adapt the bonus level. It would be easier to explain if you show your code, what default value you want, and what value is expected after the transaction (: